# Is the Azure Put Blob operation atomic?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

The documentation for Azure's [Put Blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) REST API operation tells us that it is possible to upload a block blob up to 64 MB with a single request.

I'm wondering whether such an operation is atomic. In particular I need to know whether the following assumptions are true or false.

1. If two or more clients concurrently to put a particular non-existing blob using this API specifying `If-None-Match: *`, then at most one of them will succeed.
2. A blob put using this API will never be partially exposed. It will either not exist or exist with the entire content that was put (<64MB) including metadata.

Can anyone confirm or refute these assumptions?

Comment: A side note: it is possible to upload more that 64 MB in a single request if you use _chunked upload_ , see my source code here https://azureslfileuploader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#tags/V0.1.9090/AzureSilverlightFileUploaderPlugIn/Uploader.cs for an example.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen That's not a single request upload as far as I can tell. Looks like you're uploading blocks in which case you're required to send at least two requests. Anyway, it has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have received confirmation directly from a Microsoft support technician that **both of these assumptions are true**:

1. If two or more clients concurrently to put a particular non-existing blob using this API specifying `If-None-Match: *`, then at most one of them will succeed.
2. A blob put using this API will never be partially exposed. It will either not exist or exist with the entire content that was put (<64MB) including metadata.

Answer (score 3):

**Is the Azure Put Blob operation atomic?**
Answer: Not at all.

> Any attempt to read the blob before the completion of step 3 would
>   result in HTTP 404 (not found).

Yes, 100% secure you'll receive a 404

> Any attempt to read the blob after the completion of step 3 would
>   either see the entire blob content and meta data, or result in HTTP
>   404 (not found) in case step 3 was not successful.

Yes, if the operation isn't complete there is no file in blob storage

> Any attempt to put the blob with an If-None-Match: * header before the
>   start of step 2 would have to wait until step 3 is completed, either
>   successfully in which case the request must fail with HTTP 409
>   (precondition failed) or continue normally, since the blob would not
>   exist.

In my testing: there's no wait.

So, normally after a second attempt to upload the same file name you will receive a **HTTP/1.1 409 The specified blob already exists**. (just if you have sent the request with ***If-None-Match:****  header)

The problem is that if the first upload file hasn't received yet the first 201 confirmation (or unique if you're uploading all in one request) then the second file will be allowed to create the resource even if it was launched after the first one. This use to happen if the second file is shorter than the first one because maybe in just the 1st (short ) request the file will finish the transmission.

The weirdest thing is that when this happen the first stream will continue uploading data normally until when last request is emitted, the answer for the last request will be 409.

I strongly recommend you to create a spike solution to test your specific use case because the situation described above maybe is not a valid use case for your application.

Comment: Are you sure about the part that a blob that is being put cannot be seen until it is completely uploaded? If so, it's atomic - it's either completely there or not there at all. However, you say *Not at all* as an answer to whether it's atomic. Confusing.

Comment: 1. Yes I'm 100% sure    2. the **"not at all "** part is because of the special case mentioned at the end, I mean there's no "waiting", and if the first request hasn't end before the second file start to upload there will be stored the second file not the first.

Comment: Excellent. Can you please explain why you are 100% sure - can you link to any official documentation or other credible source that says so?

Comment: I already have tested that scenario but any way  I have created an spike solution to test it again using a >50 MB file. And while running I have used fiddler to track all request and responses

Comment: I don't understand how you can be 100% sure about this from just testing.

Comment: For me past experiences and test are enough specially in this scenario you can easily create a program where you can can upload a 2 or 50 mb file and then just run 2 program instances to directly test the results with an html debugger. Nevertheless if your question was about where to find direct links to documentation or internal behaviors  in that case I have no idea where you can find that information in such level of details you're requiring in the original question. At least that information is not easy to find in Azure public docs.

Comment: Another easy test I already run in the past and I have just tested again for this topic is that any blob upload, even one with just one request, will no commit any blob file if the transaction is aborted or is not finished